# What's the fastest way to select every other vertex of an edge ring?

Tags: mesh, selection-tools

What's the fastest way, without using Python, to select every other vertex of an edge ring with an even number of verts?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In edit mode with entire edge ring selected:

*Select> Checker Deselect*

This should deselect every other vertex.

You can then use the 'offset' value in the toolshelf if you want the *other* vertices in the edge ring selected.

No Offset:

[image]

Offset by 1:

[image]

*Note:* This works in edge and face mode too, deselecting alternate edges or faces to get a checkerboard selection.

Comment: Oh boy, I'm humbled. It even takes the active vertex into account as a starting point. Thank you

Comment: I can't find the offset.

Comment: The offset option as well as the nth option (so you can select every 3rd vertex or 6th vertex...) is available in the operator options - either F6 or at the bottom of the toolbar panel T

Comment: I would like to comment is that Blender is absolutely brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

If the topology is well-formed for it, which is surprisingly often,  then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Numpad +</kbd> 'Select Next Active' will select a sequence of vertices, edges, or faces, in a pattern established by the last 2 selections:

[image]

If you switch off 'Select' on <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> *Reveal Hidden*, and make use of '*Header > Select > Select Loops > Edge Loops*'  and/or  '*Header > Select > Select Loops > Edge Rings*', then by hiding and unhiding, you can find your way to a wide range of useful patterns that are not always available through 'Checker Deselect' :

[image]